# CAML Query filter by month

Tags: filter, caml

I would like to use CAML Query to select records between a certain period (a particular month) and which where made by a certain user. Here's what it look like but it doesn't work

```
                 "<Where>"+
                    "<And>"+
                        "<And>"+
                            "<GE>"+
                                "<FieldRef Name='Date' />"+
                                "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='False'>"+
                                SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(dtStart) + 
                                "</Value>"+
                            "</GE>"+
                            "<LT>"+
                                "<FieldRef Name='Date' />" +
                                "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='False'>" +
                                SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(dtEnd) +
                                "</Value>" +
                            "</LT>"+
                        "</And>"+
                        "<Eq>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Author' />" +
                            "<Value Type='User'>" + currentUser.Name + 
                            "</Value>"+
                        "</Eq>"+
                    "</And>"+
                "</Where>" +
                "<OrderBy>"+
                    "<FieldRef Name='ClientName' Ascending='True' />"+
                    "<FieldRef Name='DateMonth' Ascending='True' />"+
                "</OrderBy>";
```

if i had to translate it into SQL command it would look similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (myTable.Date BETWEEN <aStartDate> AND <aEndDate>) AND Author = <currentUser>
```

So basicaly in CAML it's greater than dtStart and lower than dtEnd it's how i tried to make a BETWEEN translated to CAML Query.

I'm using this with C# not javascript.

Did i miss something?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few mistakes that I can figure out are, instead of `<GE>` and `<LT>`, you should use `<Geq>` and `<Leq>`...

Also while mentioning boolean True and False, make sure you use Caps like `TRUE`/`FALSE`, following is an example:

```
<Where>
    <And>
      <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
          <Value IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime"> + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(dtStart) + </Value>
      </Geq>
      <Leq>
        <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime"> + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(dtEnd) + </Value>
      </Leq>
    </And>
  </Where>
```

Reference

[CAML Query Search Between Two Date Ranges : SharePoint](http://dhondiyals.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/caml-query-search-between-two-date-ranges-sharepoint/)

Comment: Simple mistake, i've didn't use the correct Name for my ref. And Geq and Leq worked corerctly. Thanks.